# Event delegation with bind? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

You know how there are times when you want to use one eventlistener for multiple elements? Like this:

```
divWithManyLinks.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.textContent);
}
//--> text content of the clicked link
```

And you know how there are times when you want to use bind with an eventlistener to change the scope of the eventhandler? For instance, you might need to reference 'this' and point to something specific.

What if you want to have one eventlistener for multiple elements and use bind at the same time, is that possible?

In my case, I want to be able to go from one method (Example.prototype.methodA) to one of two other methods in the same object (Example.prototype.methodB or Example.prototype.methodC) based on what button is clicked. Because the eventlistener is placed inside of methodA the other methods will be referenced with this.methodB and this.methodC. I could possibly implement two eventlisteners with bind separately, but is it possible to have just one eventlistener?

```
Example.prototype.methodA = function() {
    // addEventListener that listens on both buttons and executes either this.methodB or this.methodC based on what button is clicked.
}

Example.prototype.methodB = function() {
    // do stuff
}

Example.prototype.methodC = function() {
    // do stuff
}
```

If this is bad practise or if there is a better way to do it, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, yes. Here's an example:

```
Example.prototype.methodA = function() {
    someContainerElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (/* `event.target` is a match for the first button*/) {
            this.methodB();
        } else {
            this.methodC();
        }
    }.bind(this), false);
};
```

Of course, it doesn't have to be an `if`, could be a `switch` or a map lookup or...

**Live Example:**

```js
function Example(element, name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.element = element;
  this.output = element.querySelector(".output");
}
Example.prototype.methodA = function() {
  this.element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (event.target.name == "B") {
      this.methodB();
    } else {
      this.methodC();
    }
  }.bind(this), false);
}

Example.prototype.methodB = function() {
  this.output.innerHTML =
    prep(this.name).toLowerCase();
};

Example.prototype.methodC = function() {
  this.output.innerHTML =
    prep(this.name).toUpperCase();
};

function prep(text) {
  return text.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;");
}

new Example(document.getElementById("one"), "one").methodA();
new Example(document.getElementById("two"), "two").methodA();
```

```html
<div id="one">
  The "one" element:
  <br>
  <input type="button" name="B" value="Lower">
  <input type="button" name="C" value="Upper">
  <span class="output"></span>
</div>
<div id="two">
  The "two" element:
  <br>
  <input type="button" name="B" value="Lower">
  <input type="button" name="C" value="Upper">
  <span class="output"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I was going to post the same thing, except use a switch

Comment: @epascarello: :-) I went back and forth on `switch`. It depends a lot on how he/she can tell the buttons apart.